# Repeated data entry

Tags: contacts, profile, duplicate-contacts

I work on a volunteer resource office and we use a CIVICRM to manage our organizations and their volunteer opportunities.

The organizations post "activities" in the database, however, those have been getting duplicated (at times triplicated) yet on the organization's profile, there is only one activity listed.

How can I fix that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean in the database there are multiple copies but on the screen there is only one? In the database do some of them have is_current_revision=0?

Comment: When you say 'organization's profile' do you mean a public website? If so, some more information might help, e.g. Drupal, WP, etc.? If it's Drupal and using 'Views' to display it's worth checking the field settings as there's an option to show only Primary record (e.g. if the organisation has multiple phone numbers it may duplicate the entry for each number).